# Java Inheritance - What is printed when Fly (program) is run?

Tags: java, inheritance

Given the following classes:

```
public class Super {
    protected int x = 1;

    public Super() {
    System.out.print("Super");
    }
}
```

```
public class Duper extends Super {
    protected int y = 2;
    public Duper() {
    System.out.println(" duper");
}
```

```
public class Fly extends Super {
    private int z, y;
    public Fly() {
        this(0);
    }
    public Fly(int n) {
        z = x + y + n;
        System.out.println(" fly times " + z);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Duper d = new Duper();
        int delta = 1;
        Fly f = new Fly(delta);
    }
}
```

What is printed when `Fly` is run?

My thought was since it created a Duper object, it would print out `duper`. Then, it goes to the Fly constructor with the int parameter. x is 1 from Super, y is 2 from Duper, n is 1 from Fly, so 1+2+1 = 4, so I thought it would print `fly times 4` as well. But it's actually

```
Super duper
Super fly times 2
```

If someone could explain that would be great!

Comment: y in Fly hides the y of Duper and default valie for it y is 0 so its 1+0+1 = 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Duper d = new Duper();
```

Instantiates a new `Duper`, `Duper()` constructor implicitly calls `Super()` constructor

-> **prints "Super"** (no line return)

-> then **prints "duper"** (with line return)

```
int delta = 1;
Fly f = new Fly(delta);
```

`Fly` constructor implicitly calls `Super()` constructor -> **prints "Super"** (no line return)
then calls `this(0)`.

**EDIT:** In `Fly`, `private int z, y;` initialises both `z` and `y` to `0` (this is the default value for `int`)
Then `x = 1` is inherited from `Super` so the value of `x` is then set to `1`, the value of `y` and `z` remains `0`.
And `n` is set to `1` by the constructor `public Fly(int n)` when calling `new Fly(delta)` (delta is `1`)

and calculate

```
z = x + y + n   
x is initialised to 1 in Super
y is initialised to 0 by default in Fly 
n is initialised to 1 from the constructor parameter
z = 1 + 0 + 1 
z = 2
```

Then **prints " fly times 2"** (with line return)

Comment: No. x is 1 from Super, y is 0 from Fly, n is 1, as provided as delta.

Comment: @Bentaye So, this(0) initializes z and y to be 0?

Comment: @PM123 according to JLS, properties are initialized with default value if they are not initialized in the constructor, that is false for boolean, 0 for primitives (e.g. int), and null for reference types(e.g. String, Duper, Integer). This is why y is 0, because it is not initialized in Fly. Don't get fooled by y = 2 from Duper, Duper.y and Fly.y are different properties.

Comment: @PM123 I added a little EDIT section to my answer to clarify that

Comment: @PM123 Also if you can run through the code step by step with a debugger, you can follow the whole process and see what is called and when

Answer (score 2):

Before the `Duper` constructor's body is executed, it executes the constructor of the super-class `Super`. Hence "Super" is printed before "duper".

The same applies for the `Fly` constructor.

As for the printed number, `z = x + y + n`. `x` and `n` are 1, and `y` is 0, so the sum is 2. Note that `Fly` is not a sub-class of `Duper`, and even if it was, the `y` member of `Fly` would still contain `0` and hide the `y` member of `Duper`, so it doesn't matter that `Duper` has a `y` variable initialized to 2.

Comment: So it's an implied super() command in the constructor? Also, that doesn't explain the number

Comment: @PM123 yes.....I added the explanation of the number later (missed that part originally)

Answer (score 1):

> y is 2 from Duper

No. y comes from Fly and is initialized with 0, hence the z is 2 (x = 1 from Super, y = 0 from Fly, n is delta, which is 1). You'd use `super.y` inside `Fly`'s constructor to access `Duper`'s y.

Also, for the 'Super duper', unless you explicitly call it, `super()` is automatically invoked. There might cases when you don't want `super()`, e.g. base class doesn't have a no-arg constructor, but a constructor which accepts an int, so in the derived class' constructor, you'd call it like `super(42)`.

Answer (score 1):

In the constructor of a sub class, if you don't call a constructor of the super class explicitly, the default constructor of the super class is called implicitly.

So basically, your Duper class is compiled as if it were

```
public class Duper extends Super {
    protected int y = 2;
    public Duper() {
        super(); // call Super default constructor
        System.out.println(" duper");
    }
}
```

Same goes with Fly